# How can I combine 2 pivot ( Sale and Pos Order ) into 1 pivot view on my new module?

Tags: pivot, report, python-3.6, odoo-11

I have a problem because I'm new guy in Odoo 11, my task is combine 2 pivot ( Sales and Pos Order ) into 1 pivot view of new Module that i create. So how can i do this? step by step, because I'm just new guy. Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: You can do that via creating a new model where all the necessary fields of POS order and Sale order will be there and create a new view for that.

Comment: i'm thinking about that, but can it change real time? when sale and pos have something report, my module that i created will show that report

Comment: If you have some example, please show me, i'm very grateful about that

Comment: Yes this can be real time. You just need to fetch out data on click action of menu via query.

Comment: I'm looking for information in google, and i found that I need to join 2 table report ( sale.report and report.pos.order ), in order to do that, some guide show I need to use SQL statement to join 2 table into 1 table. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. You need to join 2 tables to get data of both.

Comment: Sorry for reply lately, so JOIN FULL statement in SQL will combine all data in 2 tables, in order to excute that query, we need the condition for the same of 2 tables. How about sale and pos order? What is the same of this to make a condition for the statement SQL

Comment: `SELECT column
FROM table1
FULL [OUTER] JOIN table2
ON table1.column = table2.colum;`
What is the same to make this condition run " table1.column = table2.colum"?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use select queries for both the models and there is no need for same field or relation you can just use Union All.For Example
select pos_order as po
LEFT JOIN pos_order_line pol ON(pol.order_id = po.id)
UNION ALL
select sale_order so
LEFT JOIN sale_order_line sol ON(sol.order_id = so.id)
Hope this will help you in this regard and don't forget to define the fields you want to show on the pivot view.